# Sequelize - function on column in a where clause

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a Restaurant model with a property 'location' of the type GEOMETRY("Point"). I'm trying to write a query with sequelize that will give me all the restaurants in a certain radius:

```
models.Restaurant.findAll({
    attributes: ["*", [models.sequelize.fn("ST_Distance_Sphere", models.sequelize.fn("ST_MakePoint", latitude, longitude), models.sequelize.col("location")), "distance"]],
    where: {
        xxx: {
            $lte: radius
        }
    }
}).then(function(dishes) {
    res.status(200).json({dishes: dishes})
});
```

I have no clue what I should write where xxx is. I have tried all kinds of things but get an error every time. 
In the select query I'm first calling a function to create a point from the coordinates (latitude, longitude) where to user currently is. Then I use a function to calculate the distance to the location of the restaurant.
I'm using postgres btw.

Edit: Ended up doing it like this:

```
models.Restaurant.findAll({
    attributes: [
      'id',
      'name',
      'addressLine1',
      'addressLine2',
      'city',
      'zipPostalCode',
      'location',
      'phoneNumber',
      'website',
      [
        models.sequelize.fn(
          'ST_Distance_Sphere', models.sequelize.fn('ST_MakePoint', lat, long), models.sequelize.col('location')
        ),
        'distance',
      ],
    ],
    where: models.sequelize.and(
      models.sequelize.where(
        models.sequelize.fn(
          'ST_Distance_Sphere', models.sequelize.fn('ST_MakePoint', lat, long), models.sequelize.col('location')
        ), '>', fromRadius),
      models.sequelize.where(
        models.sequelize.fn(
          'ST_Distance_Sphere', models.sequelize.fn('ST_MakePoint', lat, long), models.sequelize.col('location')
        ), '<=', toRadius),
      models.sequelize.where(
        models.sequelize.col('Restaurant.is_online'), true
      )
    ),
  })
```

Answer (score 12):

I'm assuming *radius* is that calculated point where the user is,
xxx should be *distance*

Check the [doc](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#basics), notice the last query:

```
Model.findAll({
     where: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('FUNCTION',
            sequelize.col('field')), 'value')
});
```

Comment: Thx!! I think this is gonna work. Haven't been able to test it yet as I need to create some test data but the generated query looks ok.

Comment: @musicformellons I have updated my original post with a solution that works for me

Answer (score 4):

if you have to add a MySQL function to some where clause column along with other columns with their conditions, you can do it in this way.

```
Model.findAll({
where: {
someColumn: {[Sequelize.Op.eq]: "some value"},
columnWithFunction: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn("UPPER", Sequelize.col("columnWithFunction")), "=", "SOME UPPER CASE VALUE")
     }
,...
})
```